# Autogenerated Datagrid columns with type bool

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am using WPF datagrid. Data I am binding to the grid is not having fixed number of columns, so I have set AutoGeneratedColumns to True.

```
<DG:TestDataGrid x:Name="grTestData" ItemsSource="{Binding}" LoadingRow="grTestData_LoadingRow" UnloadingRow="grTestData_UnloadingRow" AutoGeneratingColumn="grTestData_AutoGeneratingColumn" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Visibility="Visible" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"></DG:TestDataGrid>
```

As auto-generated columns are used, where ever it encounters column of type bool it uses DataGridCheckbox columns. When user is closing the this screen, I am saving data assigned to data grid in an xml file.

```
ds.Tables[0].WriteXml(path);
//here path is the place where I am storing the xml
```

again when user is opening the sceen I am loading data from xml and assigning it back to grid.

```
ds.ReadXmlSchema(path);
ds.ReadXml(path);
grTestData.ItemsSource=ds.Table[0].DefaultView
```

Now the problem is, boolean columns are not showing checkboxes. It is showing text values in the columns "True" for checkboxes which were checked earlier and false for unchecked checkboxes. Please guide me, how can I prevent it. If you need any other info on code... plz mention it. I will paste it here.

Regards,
Priyank

Comment: For the first time, what is the datasource? How does the datagrid display the correct checkbox for the first time?

Comment: Hi for the first time I am taking data from database. It is showing the checkboxes. But as HB said, later when I save it to xml it becomes an untyped dataset. Thanks  for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the writng mode by passing System.Data.XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema into WriteXML.

```
typedDataset.WriteXml("c:\\data.xml", System.Data.XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

Comment: @Dimitry: I tried to save the xml using System.Data.XmlWriteMode, It worked perfectly. Now it saving the scheema too along with xml. :) :) my problem has been solved. Thanks a lot Dimitry.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for the `DataGrid` to know what the "intended" type of the attribute is, when you read the XML you need to parse it to a strongly typed data-structure, right now everything is considered to be a `string`.

Comment: Actually there's a way of knowing that thanks to the data schema attached to the dataset the grid might have concluded on the right type.

Comment: @Dmitry: Of course, but obviously this is not happening here.

Comment: Thanks a lot HB :) I think better if i use the typed dataset

Comment: @H.B. be more accurate with statements applying to the logical nature of thing:) Also, never suggest on things you didn't try. I've tried using a typed DS and it picked up the correct types.

Comment: @H.B. - That is wrong, my friend. The problem was with WriteXml call, your man didn't pass System.Data.XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema flag which caused the schema loss. See my answer.

Comment: Do you guys accept answers just by looking at a rate of a person who asked it?:)

Comment: @Dimitry: I tried to save the xml using System.Data.XmlWriteMode, I worked perfectly. Now it saving the scheema too along with xml. :) :) my problem has been solved. Thanks a lot Dimitry.

Comment: Good man. Always try before accepting. As otherwise you're doing no favour to anyone.

Comment: @Dimitry: I did it in hurry. I am new to the world of WPF. Trying to learn. I have marked your answer as correct one. Please don't feel bad. Once again thanks a lot :) :)

Comment: I am not. I'm just saying that as I've been here for a while and can see this as a pattern - whereby high rated people are minsuing right answers, while posting a complete nonsense themselves. You man even convienced someone to unaccept the right answer in favour of his own:) LOL.

Comment: @Dimirty: True. I have faced this things many times. If I have some doubts and I will post the question here, some people will mark it as useless question and because of that I will lose my reputation points. Which can help me to vote for the answers and help my blogmates.

Comment: That is to raise their own value - they say by that - you don't understand that it's useless, we - do. Go figure.